# How keep vector-length and positions despite NULLs

Tags: r, data.table

I must fill a vector (and then data.table) with values from functions that sometimes return NULL. This example illustrates what goes wrong:

```
library(data.table)
createNull1 <- function() {  # I do not have access to the inside of this function
  if ((i/2)%%1==0) { return("ABC") } else return(NULL)
}

createNull2 <- function() {  # I do not have access to the inside of this function
  if ( (i/2)%%1==0) { return(NULL) } else return("XYZ")
}

my.data.table <- NULL
system.time(for (i in 1:10000) {
my.vector <- c(createNull1(),
               createNull2(),
               createNull1(),
               createNull2(),
               createNull1())
my.data.table <- rbind(my.data.table, data.table(my.vector))
})
```

The resulting my.data.table have 2 columns, but should have 5. Here is why:

```
i <- 1
my.vector <- c(NULL, "ABC", NULL. "ABC", NULL)  # But 2 resulting elements, not 5
i <- 2
my.vector <- c("XYZ", NULL, "XYZ", NULL, "XYZ") # But 3 resulting elements, not 5
```

I cannot edit the functions, so the solution must be found inside the for-loop.

I need to do this literally millions of times so speed is important. The following code solves the problem...

```
my.data.table <- NULL
system.time(for (i in 1:10000) {
  my.vector <- c(if (is.null(createNull1())) NA else createNull1(),
                 if (is.null(createNull2())) NA else createNull2(),
                 if (is.null(createNull1())) NA else createNull1(),
                 if (is.null(createNull2())) NA else createNull2(),
                 if (is.null(createNull1())) NA else createNull1())
  my.data.table <- rbind(my.data.table, data.table(my.vector))
})
```

...but is more than twice as slow.

How can I create my.data.table faster?

Comment: Why can't you edit the function? Anyway, your code is slow because you grow an object in a loop (read [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)). It hurts double to see this because you tagged with data.table (but actually don't create a data.table). If you *must* use a `for` loop (why?) at least pre-allocate the matrix and assign with subsetting.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use `NULL` vs `NA`?

Comment: The functions come from packages that are much more advanced than I understand. Yes, I missed the data.table() around my.vector (in example not in the real code).

Comment: NULL comes from the functions, NA are OK too.

Comment: I agree for-loops should be avoided, but there is a lot calculated "per i" that become inputs to the functions so it is difficult to vectorize. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pre-allocating and using `set`:

```
dt = data.table(a = rep(NA_character_,10000),
                b = NA_character_, c = NA_character_,
                d = NA_character_, e = NA_character_)

for (i in 1:10000) {
  if (is.null(v1 <- createNull1()))
    v1 = NA_character_
  if (is.null(v2 <- createNull2()))
    v2 = NA_character_

  set(dt, i, 1L, v1)
  set(dt, i, 2L, v2)
  set(dt, i, 3L, v1)
  set(dt, i, 4L, v2)
  set(dt, i, 5L, v1)
}
```